# What is the difference between :something => true and something: true in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this Capabara method that takes an option:

```
page.should have_selector("#jFooterStandardLinks", :visible => true)
```

The option can also be provided like:

```
page.should have_selector("#jFooterStandardLinks", visible: true)
```

Both methods work but I am getting an error in Eclipse IDE.

- What is the difference between `:visible => true` and `visible: true`?
- Is `visible:` still interpreted as a Ruby symbol?

Comment: In this case, there's no difference, and yes, it's a symbol. It is Ruby 1. 9 hash syntax.

Comment: If you're getting an error in Eclipse it's likely you don't have the Ruby language level set to 1.9. Note that doing some simple tests in `irb` could have answered the basic questions about the two hash syntaxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. `symbol: value` is an alias for `:symbol => value`, only that first is not compatible to ruby 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference. Ruby accepts `key: value` hash syntax while the keys are symbols. Thus

```
x_method @blah, some_key: 'asdf', another_key: 3, yet_a_key: true # is equivalent to:
x_method(@blah, {:some_key => 'adsf', :another_key => 3, :yet_a_key => true })
```

The first syntax is not available in ruby 1.8.7 as @ckruse noted.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is the transition from ruby 1.8x to 1.9x. For now it's still exactly the same, but it could be that :visible => true will eventually be deprecated in favor of visible: true.

The new syntax is slightly simpler and cleaner and has closer resemblance to JSON.

Concerning your second question, here's a nice quote I've found:

> "The new notation is sort of a syntactic sugar for the most common style of hashes out there, the so called symbol to object hash. If you do this in the irb, you’ll see ruby returning the old school hash, with the symbols used as keys:"

```
new_hash = {simon: "Talek", lorem: "Ipsum"}
# => {:simon=>"Talek", :lorem=>"Ipsum"}
```

> "If you need to have arbitrary objects as your hash keys, you’ll still have to do it old school."

Source: http://breakthebit.org/post/8453341914/ruby-1-9-and-the-new-hash-syntax

Comment: No, it couldn't be that it would be deprecated. How would that even work? Where did you hear that? That has never been the plan, and it cannot even be done.

Comment: It's not very likely, but theoretically it could be done. That is another discussion though. When ruby 1.9 came out it sparked some interest and this post https://peepcode.com/blog/2011/rip-ruby-hash-rocket-syntax caused some rumors. Nothing substantial, nor will it in the near future.

Comment: Obscure blog posts by random dudes on the intarwebz don't make a deprecation. An official statement by matz and an entry in the ChangeLog does. Anyway, the hashrocket syntax *cannot* be deprecated in favor of the colon syntax, because the colon syntax isn't a *replacement*. It only works for an extremely tiny subset of the cases where the hashrocket syntax works.